# How to provide default filename for showSaveFilePicker

Tags: javascript, html, native-file-system-api-js

I am wanting to provide a spinner in my web app as I download a file from the server and then save it using the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API).

I can do this using the [showSaveFilePicker()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/showSaveFilePicker) but it seems very odd that I can't specify a default filename. I know what the filename of the file that I am downloading is so I want to suggest that to the user as the name of the file they should save it as. At the moment my user needs to come up with a name each time they are downloading it.

It seems very odd that I can't do this! There must be a way!

Comment: It is discussed heavily and seems to be "on the road": https://github.com/w3ctag/design-reviews/issues/598

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is now supported as of Chrome 91 and you can specify a suggested file name as part of the parameters:

```js
const handle = await self.showSaveFilePicker({
  suggestedName: 'README.md',
  types: [{
    description: 'Markdown',
    accept: {
      'text/markdown': ['.md'],
    },
  }],
});
```

On older versions the `suggestedName` will just silently be ignored, so it's safe to add it today!